# How to create the tables and import the data to sql in MariaDb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Whenever  type `mysql -u username [-p password] database_name < tatoeba_database.sql`

I get

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mys
>   ql -u root tatoeba < tatoeba_database.sql' at line 1
>   MariaDB [tatoeba]>

Is there another way to do such thing Am I missing something?

P.S. I'm following this article: https://github.com/Tatoeba/tatoeba2/wiki/How-to-install-Tatoeba

Answer (score 1):

Remove  [-p password]

```
 mysql -u username -p database_name < tatoeba_database.sql
```

and enter the password manually

Comment: Thanks, @scanEdge - I have removed and the problem persists ...

Comment: seems you have a space between   mys and gl  'mys ql' is a typo or not??

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you type your command **in MariaDB prompt** (that is, you start `mysql` client first and then use the command above). It's incorrect. You either need to execute it from the **shell** prompt, or, if you want to start `mysql` client first, lose the whole thing and run instead

```
source tatoeba_database.sql
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I'm too newbie on that. so should I start the shell from xampp and type `mysql -u username [-p password] database_name < tatoeba_database.sql`?